# Google Apps Engine Datastore Search

Tags: python, google-app-engine, search, google-cloud-datastore

I was wondering if there was any way to search the datastore for a entry. I have a bunch of entries for songs(title, artist,rating) but im not sure how to really search through them for both song title and artist. We take in a search term and are looking for all entries that "match." But we are lost :( any help is much appreciated!

- We are using python

edit1: current code is useless, its an exact search but might help you see the issue

```
   query = song.gql("SELECT * FROM song WHERE title = searchTerm  OR  artist = searchTerm")
```

Comment: You need to define what constitues a 'match' before we can help. Simple indexing might work here, or it might be necessary to use fulltext search, all depending on what criteria  you want to filter on.

Comment: I wanted to just use fulltext if possible but dont really know how to implement that with app engine

Comment: You still haven't described what sort of searches you want/need to perform on this data.

Answer (score 1):

The song data you work with sounds as a rather static data set (primarily inserts, no or few updates). In that case there is GAE technique called Relation Index Entity (RIE) which is an efficient way to implement keyword-based search.

But some preparation work required which is briefly:

- build special RIE entity where you place all searchable keywords
  from each song (one-to-one relationship).
- RIE stores them in `StringListProperty` which supports searches like this: 
  `keywords = 'SearchTerm'`
  (returns True if any of the values in the list `keywords` matches 'SearchTerm'`)
- AND condition works immediately by adding multipe filters as above
- OR condition needs more work by implementing in-memory merge from AND-only queries

You can find details on solution workflow and code samples in my blog [Relation Index Entities with Python for Google Datastore](http://novyden.blogspot.com/2011/09/efficient-keyword-search-with-relation.html).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.billkatz.com/2009/6/Simple-Full-Text-Search-for-App-Engine